# Can curl interactively ask for username addition to password?

Tags: curl

Is there a way to make curl ask for the username, when using basic http authentication ?

If I use `-u <username>` it will ask for the password, but I would like a solution where it interactively ask for the username first

Comment: are you using a *nix shell (bash, or other)? The all can prompt for input and save to a variable, i.e. `printf "Enter UserName: " ; read userName ; curl .... "$usrName" ...` .. But voting to close. You're asking how to use a program not how to fix an error in your programming code. (IMHO). Better to include more information wherever you post your Q. Please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Comment: As far as being on-topic I would think curl falls into the `software tools commonly used by programmers;` but maybe I'm stretching it ?